# Android Testing application

Tags: android, testing

I am new to android. And we already have an project on android and I am supposed to develop an application that will do the API dependency checking on Android. 
I have to check whatever APIs we use will successfully run and are not deprecated in the newer Android version or Google APi version. 
So for this i have to write an Testing application. 
Do I need to write an Android test application or normal Java application can do this?
I tried writing Java application and giving some basic calls from it but I get lots errors like
import com.google.common. cannot be resolved
TYPE_MAP not supported
Lists cannot be resolved

and basically the first error cannot be resolved. So do i need to create an android test application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is whatever API you are using should successfully run on the android.So write an android test application and make sure whether it is compiling or deprecated one.

Comment: Yes thanks,I wrote an Java application and now i can test the API.